# Android studio build fast but run wrong in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

Exactly my problem, if I have small change in app about display UI (modify activity code or resource layout), Android studio build very fast and then run my app in emulator without kill "previous version" process (running in emulator), sometime it's run and display correct, but sometime it doesn't run correct what I want, I must kill process manual and rebuild project, it takes a lot of time, and makes me confused because I don't know where go wrong, 
I thought this is my bug.

It happen recently when I update Android studio, I think this feature is very powerful and helpful, application mustn't rerun from the beginning whenever build new version.

But how to enabled/disabled "fast build", sometime I want Android studio build my project normally.

Comment: There is one button named "Rerun <yourprojectname>", try that.

Comment: You can also disable Instant Run from Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run - Just disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solution:

1)You can also disable `Instant Run` from `Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run` - and disable it

2)Clean Project when studio doesn't build properly

Comment: no it cannot be changed path of instant run is same and it didn't copied your statement and i also suggested a alternative that i use heavily

Answer (score 1):

Press the `stop` button before running the app and then run the app so dialog will be displayed to choose the emulator.

[image]